# css response displays differently

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

one issue I don't quite understand.
I made an online sample, when I'm resizing the window, the SPANs response one by one.
Online sample  http://jsfiddle.net/Pva7y/1/

Online Images
[image]
[image]

However, I copied the same code to my local html, the SPANs response just together. 
Local Image.

why different? Thanks

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="row ">
    <div class="span7 blue">
    1
    </div>
    <div class="span2 red">
       2
   </div>
    <div class="span3 green">
      3
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.blue{background-color:blue;}
.red{background-color:red;}
.green{background-color:green;}
```

Comment: unable to paste code properly, says"Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code" http://jsfiddle.net/Pva7y/1/

Comment: Is your local site also loading bootstrap.css?

Comment: @olo: Fixed that for you.

Comment: @Terry yes! loads bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you forgot to use `container` div. Correct pattern is

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
      1 2 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See corrected [jsfiddle (1)](http://jsfiddle.net/Pva7y/2/).

Next, if you want your page to be responsive and fit the layout to the size of the viewport you have to also include `bootstrap-responsive.css`. See [jsfiddle (2)](http://jsfiddle.net/Pva7y/3/). In your local HTML you used either both `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap-responsive.css` or prior files merged to one CSS for reducing client-server requests number.

Answer (score -1):

Your `<div>`s are floated in your Fiddle, but they are not floated in your local html judging from your screenshot. And since bootstrap.css floats the `<div>` element with a class of span, I am guessing that bootstrap.css is not loaded properly in your local html file.

A way to troubleshoot your issue is to check the Inspector (if you're using Chrome), or Firebug (if you're using Firefox). Look at the computer style of the three `<div>`s in your fiddle AND your local html, and compare them. They must have been styled differently because they look different on the same browser, so that's the way to start troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks. I put bootstrap.css in the folder and linked it, `<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`, shouldn't be wrong

Comment: Check the Inspector. How are the elements in the two pages differently styled?

Comment: Thanks! SPAN changes to `width: 100%;` on local, but the size on jsfiddle.net stays the `width` as it is. Using Chrome